# Will a generator turn a lamp on in open circuit if the lamp is connected to the earth which is greedy for electrons?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity

Consider the following thought experiment.

> One end of a lamp is connected to one terminal of a power generator. The other end of the lamp is connected to the ground via a metal copper as follows. Assume that the generator is placed quite far above the ground.

[image]

Physics textbooks say that our earth is a giant capacitor that is greedy for electrons. It is also said that electric current flows if there is a closed circuit.

## Question

In this scenario, will the generator turn the lamp on?

## Attempt

I am not sure whether the generator should turn the lamp on or not.

- If the generator turns on the lamp, there are electrons flowing from the generator to the earth. But how can the generator produce electrons from mechanical energy? It seems it violates the conservation of charges. So it should not turn the lamp on.
- But borrowing an analogy of our electric outlet, if we touch the live (hot) wire without wearing high impedance shoes, we will get electric shock even there is no closed circuit  (as far as I know).

[image]

Comment: Well, what do you think?

Comment: @BobD: I am not sure. If the generator turn the lamp on, there are flowing electrons from  the generator to the earth. But it does not make sense that the generator can produce electrons from mechanical energy of the wind. :-)

Comment: Do you see a complete circuit here?

Comment: @BobD: If we touch the live (hot) wire without wearing insulated shoes, we get electric shock, right? There is no closed circuit also (I think).

Comment: I'm addressing your first bullet. How would the current to the lamp return to the 300 v generator?

Comment: @BobD: No return to the generator. The earth absorbs the electrons.

Comment: Will the lamp turn on?

Comment: @BobD: Maybe yes. But if so, how can the generator produces electrons from mechanical energy of the wind. It seems to violate the conservation of charges.

Comment: What is a cupper?

Comment: @PM2Ring: I meant copper. I misspelled it. Sorry.

Comment: A generator does not "produce" electrons. They provide an electric field that forces free electrons already present in the generator windings and the circuit.  But to move the electrons continuously through the lamp you need a return path to the generator, which you don't have.

Comment: @BobD: OK. But if I touch the hot wire of electric outlet and I get electric shock (continuously to death), what is the return path?

Comment: The neutral in your drawing has to be connected to the ground to complete a circuit.

Comment: @BobD: Oh really, but it will make us in danger, right? Why do we need to make a complete path that is dangerous to us?

Comment: I'm now wondering just what the thing in a circle labeled "hot" and "neutral" is? What is it connected to?

Comment: @BobD: Please kindly see my last edited photo.

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy If you live in the US what you show as neutral is actually connected to the earth in the system. Check out the Wikipedia article "Earthing System" and in particular the diagram for the TN-C-S earthing system which is typical US residential. Note that the neutral is grounded. That completes the circuit with you in it so you can get an electric shock.

Comment: @BobD: OK. Thank you very very much for your enlightenment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happens if the $300V$ wind generator tries to create a current in the wire.

[image]

At first some electrons will move e.g. to the right in the wire above.

However this leaves one end of the wire positively charged and the electrons are attracted back, within a short time the $300V$ would not be able to move any more electrons and the current stops.

So a closed circuit is necessary for a current to flow.